# How can I store key-value pairs in JSON to be deserialized in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have data in JSON like so:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "key": true,
    "otherKey": 10
}
```

The key is a String and the value is a primitive (int, float, double, long, etc.) or a String. I want a simple, cast-free wrapper for each of the above.

Here's my wrapper class:

```
public final class Wrapper<T> {

    private String key;
    private T value;

}
```

If I specified `Wrapper[] wrappedValues` in an object to be deserialized, could I (using Jackson or GSON) deserialize the map to a list of the wrapper?

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the input you specified can never be deserialized into an array or collection because it isn't one.  a json collection of pairs of key-value looks like this

```
[
    {"foo": "bar"},
    {"key": true},
    {"otherKey": 10}
]
```

and it can be deserialized into a collection of `Wrappers` if you make the class like this

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    private String key;
    private T value;
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String key, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = (T)value;
    }
    public String toString() {  // just for nice printing
        return key + "=" + value.toString();
    }
}
```

and then you have to tell Jackson what is the generic type of the collection that will host the deserialized json:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "[ {\"foo\": \"bar\"}, {\"key\": true}, {\"otherKey\": 10} ]";

    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"))) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaType listWrappersType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory()
                .constructCollectionType(List.class, Wrapper.class);
        List<Wrapper> list = objectMapper.readValue(is, listWrappersType);
        System.out.println(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
[foo=bar, key=true, otherKey=10]
```

If you just want to load pairs of key-value and not worry about type of value, then with Jackson you can load it all into `Map<String, ?>`

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"key\": true, \"otherKey\": 10 }";
        try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8")))  {
            Map<String, ?> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(is, Map.class);
            // print map contents
            System.out.println(map);
            // print type of map values
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue().getClass()+ ", "));
            System.out.println();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

output

```
{foo=bar, key=true, otherKey=10}
foo=class java.lang.String, key=class java.lang.Boolean, otherKey=class java.lang.Integer,
```

Comment: By "array" I mean array of key:value pairs (like what you had), but I'd much prefer key:value JSON rather than an array of JSON objects, due to the nature of my project. So if I have this: `{"key":"value", "a":10}`, I want to convert it to a Java array of my wrapper (above). It's basically a map where the value can be anything but a JSON object, which is why a wrapper was necessary. If you have a solution that doesn't involve one, I'm all for it.

If this isn't possible or I'm crazy for trying, feel free to let me know and I can work with the JSON array system.

Comment: I essentially just want a Map<String, ?> except the value is bound to be any JSON type (String, float, long, etc.) except an Object. I created the wrapper to try and reduce casting, but if it's not possible I can adapt my solution.

Comment: What if you had a list of json objects, each of which contained an unspecified number of K,V pairs with unknown keys and unknown value types. How do you parse something like that?  Picture an array of objects like the OP showed in the example ... except each object had a random number of KV pairs.